# Which TV Station Benefits More from Mutual Program Broadcasting: A with More Viewers or B with Fewer?

Tags: game-theory, dominant-strategy

If there are two television stations, A and B, producing similar programs, and A has many more viewers than B due to they started earlier, then if both stations allow each other to broadcast their programs for free, their respective audiences might be attracted to the other's channel. In this situation, which television station would benefit more?

If television station B proposes to stop the mutual broadcasting in order to prevent station A from gaining more viewers, is such an action rational for station B?

Is there an economic model that studies this issue?